# How can I see the *real* raw values from a raw file?

Tags: raw

I want to do some performance tests concerning what the ISO setting "really does", whether ETTR makes sense, measure the noise, etc. on my camera.

Rather than look at the pixels after it's been Bayer decoded, mapped, reconstructed, etc. I'd like to look at the *real* raw data; that is, the sensor sample values.  Ideally it would be three matrices for R, G, and B components (with G being twice the size in both dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

On the referenced “duplicate” thread, I found RawDigger:

> Exposure Edition is for everyday use and is intended to help those who are serious about extracting the maximum quality from the camera to get precise exposures.

That looks like exactly what I'm doing.  This was pointed out by @IliahBorg, one of the developers.  Hopefully that means that they are active in the forums and helpful in using the tool.